# entityframework search value only to search not to update

Tags: entity-framework

I build a Repository just like Codefirst demo.

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query);
        }
        else
        {
            return query;
        }
    }
```

But this search has a problem.

Sometimes other person use 'get' function to search value and this value will be used as param inside other function.

Just like this:

```
UserInfoBll userInfoBll = new UserInfoBll();
        UserInfo userInfo = userInfoBll.Get(p => p.UserCode == "8001", null, "CorpShop").First();
        ConsumeProcess.process(userInfo);
```

If userInfo value change in function ConsumeProcess.process when I process savechange.

It will update something I don't want to update, so I want to find a way. The search value is just for search, when value change it, not to update the value.

For this way I wrote this:

```
public virtual List<TEntity> GetList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        List<TEntity> tEntityList = Get(filter, orderBy, includeProperties).ToList();
        SetEntityStates(EntityState.Detached, tEntityList);
        return tEntityList;
    }

protected void SetEntityStates(EntityState entityState, IEnumerable<TEntity> tEntity_params)
    {
        foreach (TEntity tEntity in tEntity_params)
        {
            if (tEntity != null)
            {
                context.Entry(tEntity).State = entityState;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now it won't update, if somebody changed search value. But there is another problem.
If I use code like this, the property which is included can't get

```
UserInfoBll userInfoBll = new UserInfoBll();
        userInfo = userInfoBll.GetList(p => p.UserCode == "8001", null, "CorpShop").First(); // CorpShop is include property
        corpShop = userInfo.CorpShop; //userInfo.CorpShop is null
```

Comment: You're updating values you don't want to update? I would want to get to the root of the problem, not just fight the symptoms as you do in your `GetList` method. What doe `ConsumeProcess.process` do?

Comment: @Gert Arnold ConsumeProcess.process don't change userInfo but i don't know why when I prcess savechange function. A sql of update about userInfo has excuted. and the value has changed . so I think the reason is search value's status context.Entry(tEntity).State = EntityState.modify ,so i change the status , because if I want to change value I should process Update function ,not change the value from get function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `IQueryable`, the easiest way to get entities disconnected from `db` is to use the `AsNoTracking` method.

```
public virtual List<TEntity> GetList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
{
    return = Get(filter, orderBy, includeProperties).AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```